# Direction Field For $\frac{dy}{dt}=2t-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out how to draw the direction field for $y'=\frac{dy}{dt}=2t-1$, but I am used to having $y$ in the equation. Does this mean $y'$ is a constant function? How would I draw this? Do I set certain values of $t$ and draw horizontal lines?

Comment: You just get $y(t) = t^2 - t + C$, where $C$ is determined by the initial condition. So no, $y(t)$ is not a constant function, it's a parabola in the $(t, y(t))$ plane. Its derivative, $y'(t)$, is a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any point $(t, y)$, draw your line segment with slope $2t - 1$ (it isn't that different from when you have $y$).

Note that in this case, all the points on a given vertical line should have the same slope (since $y$ doesn't affect it).

Comment: Is it possible to still do a phase line analysis?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Direction fields are usually generated by computer. To do it by hand, you'd select a set of points, generally evenly spaced apart, calculate the gradient at each point, and then draw a short line segment with the respective gradient centered about that point.

For example, the gradient associated with $(0, 0)$ by the differential equation you provided is $y^\prime=2(0)-1=-1$. Thus you would draw a short line segment with gradient $-1$ centered about $(0,0)$, say a line segment with end points $(-0.25, 0.25)$ and $(0.25, -0.25)$. Similarly, you'd draw a short line segment with gradient $1$ centered about $(1,0)$. Repeat for a large number of points and you'll have a slope field. To draw a (rough) sketch of $y$, put your pen down at your initial point and then simply draw a curve that is parallel to the field at all points.

The idea behind this is that we can often sketch rough graphs of $y$ (as long as we have a starting point) without actually solving the differential equation.